# Using tuples when constructing inductive types

Tags: coq

I'm trying to use a pair to pass as an argument into an inductive type in Coq

```
Definition pair := (nat,nat).

Inductive use_pair :=
  | mktriplet : pair -> nat -> use_pair.
```

However, this gives the error:

```
Error: In environment
use_pair : Type
The term "pair" has type "(Set * Set)%type"
which should be Set, Prop or Type.
```

I can get this to work

```
Inductive use_pair :=
  | mktriplet : (Set * Set) -> nat -> use_pair.
```

But I would like to specify that the *only* tuple which will work is `(nat,nat)`.

How can I specify this? I see the notation scope `%type` but that seems different than `Type`, though I don't know how to experiment with this; `Check type` returns an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you mean to do this?

```
Definition pair : Type := nat * nat.

Inductive use_pair :=
  | mktriplet : pair -> nat -> use_pair.
```